# Access Violation when touching dynamic form?

Tags: delphi, dynamic

I am creating a form dynamically, however the routine that closes it, is located in my Main Form's unit, because it's associated with a control on my Main Form (TSkype). The event is **SkypeAsyncSearchUsersFinished**. I try to set the ModalResult to mrOk of my dynamic form, when the **SkypeAsyncSearchUsersFinished** routine finishes. However, this produces an Access Violation.

This is the code that fires when the search has finished:

```
   if SIDList.Count = 0 then
   begin
     frmSearcher.tmrFadeOut.Enabled := True;
   end;
```

I tried debugging it, and I set a breakpoint at **frmSearcher.tmrFadeOut**... and I step to the next line (routine End;), and thats when the AV arises.

The **tmrFadeOutTimer** event does the **ModalResult := mrOk;**

This is how I create my dynamic form:

```
Function ShowSearcher():Boolean;
Var
   dlg : TfrmSearcher;
Begin
  Result := False;
  dlg := TfrmSearcher.Create(Forms.Application);


  dlg.tmrFadeIn.Enabled := True;


    if dlg.ShowModal = mrOk then
         Begin
         // Do nothing here

         End;

  Result := True;
  dlg.Release;

End;
```

**Yes**, I am sure that the timer only gets enabled once. :)

**Yes**, I am sure the form is "alive". :)

Actually, if I remove the tmrFadeOut.Enabled code, everything works fine, but the form does not get closed. Doing **frmSearcher.ModalResult := mrOk;** also produces an AV.

If you need more info, I will add it. :)

Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Could you post the exact text of the error message? That can help.

Comment: Code like `frmSearcher.tmrFadeOut.Enabled := True;` and `dlg.tmrFadeIn.Enabled := True;` means that outside of `TfrmSearcher`, you have knowledge on the inner structure of that form. You shouldn't: make a property or set of methods on `TfrmSearcher` to encapsulate the inner workings of `TfrmSearcher`.

Comment: @Mason - It's an Access Violation. The error code depends on if I enable the timer, or set the ModalResult. :)

Comment: @Jeroen Yeah, now when you mention it.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're manually creating the **TfrmSearcher** form, remove the IDE-generated variable **frmSearcher**, fix the compiling errors you'll get and you'll be fine.

You get the AV because **frmSearcher** is NIL.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that when I get home! Will report back of course! Haha, I really need to make a list of what causes an AV. :P

Comment: @Cosmin - So how do I call the tmrFadeOut.Enable, if I got no frmSearcher? Remember that I am calling the tmrFadeOut from a procedure in frmMain. :) Would I just use the `frmSearcher` instead of `dlg`?

Comment: No, don't use `frmSearcher`. Move the `dlg` variable from `ShowSearcher()` routine to the private section of your Main form's class. You then use `dlg` to do `dlg.tmrFadeOut.Enabled := True`. I'd also do `dlg := nil` right after that, to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Cosmin - Where should I do Dlg := Nil? I will free the form once the search is done :)

Comment: Doing `Dlg := nil` is optional, and if done, it's supposed to go right after `dlg.tmrFadeOut.Enable := True`. You'd do that in order to spot future errors easier.

Comment: @Cosmin - Well, wont the dlg be Nil when I do Dlg.free?

Comment: @Yes it would, didn't notice that :( Use `FreeAndNil(dlg)` instead of `dlg.Free`. While `FreeAndNil()` is frowned upon by advanced and experienced users, I think it'll help you. The idea's to immediately get an AV if you later touch `dlg`: When you see the AV you now you did something wrong and inspecting the content of dlg you'll immediately know what's going on. If `dlg` keeps it's value after doing `dlg.Free`, you might touch it again and cause a difficult to track AV.

Comment: @Jeff: AVs are caused by illegal memory access.  There are basically two things that cause it: dereferencing a pointer or object reference that's set to **nil**, or dereferencing a pointer or object reference that's set to a garbage value because it's either not initialized yet or it's been corrupted somehow.

Comment: @Mason - I have heard the term "dereferencing" before, however I am not sure what it means. I looked it up, but didn't find an answer I could use. Would you mind explaining in 3 sentences or less what it is? Thank you :)

Comment: @Jeff: Understanding it properly requires a knowledge of pointers that would take more than three sentences.  The simple version, though, is that when working with objects, any time you invoke any member of the object (property, field or method,) you're dereferencing the object reference.  In other words, the variable is a reference (pointer) to the actual object in memory, and you're following it to the memory it points (refers) to. If the pointer isn't valid, then you'll get an access violation.

Comment: To fix the compiler errors in the dynamic form, for example, you need to replace `Form1` (or whatever) with `Self`.

Answer (score 6):

You are assigning your new `TfrmSearcher` object instance to a local `dlg` variable that no other method has access to.  Your other routines are trying to access the dialog using a `frmSearcher` variable that you are not assigning any value to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this as an answer because I want to format code. It's not an attempt to answer the question and I'll likely delete in due course, especially if I get lots of down-votes (peer pressure).

What I wanted to show is how to create, show and destroy a form.  You do it like this:

```
procedure ShowMyForm;
var
  Form: TMyForm;
begin
  Form := TMyForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In your code:

1. There is no need to pass an owner to the constructor since you are determining the life of the form.
2. The return variable of the function is pointless since you always return `True`. The only failure mode is via an exception but then the function has no return value.
3. Don't call `Release` where you did, plain old `Free` is what you want. You call `Release` when handling a message and you want the form to go away once any messages currently in the queue are dealt with.

Comment: Even though its not the answer, I still +1 it, as it is helpfull for me. Thanks David!

Comment: The reason I used the code I posted, was because I usually use that template when I pass and return data from the form, like when adding something. So, doing it my way, should be when I am passing some data back and forth (and I need to know if the Modal result is mrOk), but when I just want to show a form, I use yours. Correct?

Comment: @Jeff Points are 1 and 3 apply in the situations you talk about also. If you are needing information back from the form, e.g. whether the user clicked OK or Cancel, then pass that back as and when needed. It's generally considered a bad idea to keep around variables that are never used. It's easy to fall into traps later on when you modify the code and it also makes the code longer and denser which affects readability and makes it harder for you to make the code correct, always your no.1 goal.

Comment: @David - so if I were to use your code, and I would need to do return stuff to the caller of the function, how would I in the function determine when ModalResult = mrOk?

Comment: @Jeff Change the code! Turn `procedure ShowMyForm` into `procedure ShowMyForm(out MyReturnVariable: TMyReturnVariableType)`.

Comment: @David- Yes, I knew that, but shall I add `if Form.ModalResult = mrOk then MyReturnVariable := Something;` after the ShowModal?

Comment: @David - Just changed my code to yours. When I enable my Fade In Timer after ShowModal, nothing happens. I only see objects that are not affected by my Transition FX.

Comment: @Jeff Your fade in timer should be enabled before you call ShowModal.

Comment: @David - Thanks! It works now! How did you know that? Why was that what I had to do? :)

Comment: @Jeff ShowModal blocks and doesn't return until the form has closed. You need to get your timer running before you go into ShowModal which in turn pumps your message queue and so picks up the timer messages. That said you would be much better off putting the transition FX inside the form and switching the timer on from TForm.OnShow. That's what Jeroen was talking about.

Comment: @David - **That said you would be much better off putting the transition FX inside the form and switching the timer on from TForm.OnShow. That's what Jeroen was talking about.** - I am not sure what you mean by the"putting the transition FX inside the form"?

Comment: @Jeff It's better practice to let objects act on their own members wherever reasonable. Here you are poking `Form.tmrFadeIn` from outside the form. Better would be to handle `TForm.OnShow` or override `TForm.DoShow` and start the timer than. That's called encapsulation. Things on the outside don't need to know about the particular implementations of the object.

Comment: Aaah, so I should enable the timer in OnShow instead? I guess thats more of a proffesional structure? :)

Comment: @Jeff By George I think you've got it!!

Comment: @David - Well, the reason I asked was because it was already working. "If it aint broken, don't fix it", you know? :P But yeah, I am glad that you guys tell me these things, because I will go to school for Datamatics, where all they teach you >>

Comment: >> is how to correctly structure your code. :P (Of course theres more to it, but thats what I was told :) )

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, we're only telling you this stuff 'cos we know you are young and learning and we're just trying to be helpful. We all had to learn it once!

Comment: @David - And I apreciate it. :) Thanks again!